# Search does not return results

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, search

As i described in the title i don't get any results when i search for a product.
I have tried so far:

1. Checking the visibility of the products
2. My products are in stock
3. I have also set the qty to 100 to be sure
4. I have updated the products attributes under catalog->manage products-> select all products.
5. I assigned all the products in the main website for my certain store view.
6. The name attribute can be used for search.

I have also tried to search with the `sku` but nothing happens again.
The odd is that the advanced search with both name and `sku`works.

And my problem remains.. Any ideas on how to make my products to appear when searched??

Comment: whether its an simple or configurable? did you reindexed?

Comment: i have 2 simple products and the rest are configurable. I have reindex many times so far.

Comment: Are the products visible in the catalog?

Comment: what do you mean by that? You mean if i can see them under catalog->manage products? If that is your question, then yes i can see them.

Comment: I mean are they visible when browsing the catalog on the front end?

Comment: Yes there are visible, and all my categories work fine.

Comment: And do they have the status 'enabled'?

Comment: Ah ok, that's strange

Comment: Yes they are enabled.

Comment: Did you reindex all indexes, or only the search index?

Comment: Yes i have reindexed all indexes.

Comment: I am using varnish also, is there any possibility that is varnish to blame for not getting any results from search?

Comment: @Vsld did you create the products via the admin, import or script?

Comment: I have created the comments via the admin.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party search such as SOLR or Sphinx?

Comment: Visibility needs to be catalog,search  and not catalog

Comment: i am using the default search from the theme and yes visibility is set to catalog,search.

Comment: Do you use custom template? is there is catalogsearch.xml in your theme? did you try to remove it or replace it with original?

Comment: Do you have only one store and one storeview? This can happen if you're in one store searching for products that belong to the root category assigned to a different store.

Comment: varnish can be an issue, can u disable it and clear cache and search again.

Comment: i'll try that and i'll give a feedback.

Comment: You could also check if the table catalogsearch_fulltext is filled with data

Comment: i will do that too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open your file `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer` and in method

```
public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
```

before `return $this;`

Add following rows:

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelectSQL(1), false, 'search.log', true);
Mage::log((array)Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->catalogsearch, false, 'search.log', true)
```

(it's for debug purpose to understand your problem).

Then open your `var/log/search.log` and put result to your first post (there should be long sql query and array where we can see rewrites).

Comment: i will give a try in the morning and tell you the results.

Answer (score 6):

I've experienced this.  My fix was to go to `Manage Products` and select all products and perform an `"Update Attributes"` from the dropdown above the grid.  In the Update Attributes screen, move to the `Websites` tab and re-associate with the proper website by checking the checkbox under `Add Products To Website`.

After this, another Search Index rebuild may be required.

Comment: I had this issue also and Update Attributes worked for me.

Comment: Read pt. #4 and #5 He already did it and his products are assigned on necessary website

Comment: @zhartaunik In #4, OP didn't specify what attributes were modified and in #5 OP uses term "Store View" which is different from "Website."

Comment: i am going to try that in a while.

Comment: i tried that and nothing, i remembered that i did that once again and got the same, nothing in return.

Answer (score 3):

go to

`admin->attributs->manage attribute-> search sku - open it -> 
Frontend Properties->  Use in Quick Search (YES )`

, Use in Advanced Search (YES).  thats it.

Comment: i have done that but nothing happend.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create external modules that required using search? Look at the layout files for something like this

```
<mdg_giftregistry_search_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block name="giftregistry.search" type="core/template" template="mdg/search.phtml" as="giftregistry_search"/>
    </reference>
</mdg_giftregistry_search_index>
```

Comment: I did not use any external module that required search.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility that worked for me is **make data reindex**!

To do this, go to the **Admin Panel > System > Index Management**, click "Select All", in field "Action" select "Reindex Data" and click "Submit".

=)

Peace!

Answer (score 1):

Many question Possibleproducts attributes set error.
you need  [image]

Check each .

Answer (score 1):

You can debug collection  object on class Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer
below funtion.

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection');
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }
```

> echo $collection->getSelect();die('test');

```
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: this code snippet where do i have to put it ?

Comment: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php
After line no 44
echo $collection->getSelect();die('test');

Comment: and the result will be? i mean i will see if the products are added to the $collection?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue few days back, My issue was i've override the default magento functionality for one extension. So it was having conflictions with my search results. Check all your extensions once may be there any confliction.

Comment: i'll do that and i'll keep you informed

Comment: can you do cache,index refresh ? it need this.

Comment: http://localhost/.../index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/                try with this , put your site link and after that  catalogsearch/advanced/   , if you get any clue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & I tried all the suggestions above & none of them worked so I did some google searching of each of my issues & got nothing, then I Googled how to make my products searchable in my Magento store & I came across "Search Terms" which is located in Catalog but not the Catalog in System Configuration but the Catalog when you add a New or edit a product. In the search query  you add the title you want to give that search & in the Redirect you put the whole URL address of the product or products you want to come up with that name. I sell sex toys so for example I typed in my search section of Magento Vibrator & none would come up even though I have heaps of different models, so I created a search query named Vibrator & copied the URL from the vibrator category & now when I search for vibrator all my vibrators come up

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too.

Going to Manage Products and select all products and perform an "Update Attributes" from the dropdown above the grid. In the Update Attributes screen, move to the Websites tab and re-associate with the proper website by checking the checkbox under Add Products To Website.

- this solution works for me but I have literally thousands of products and this would take days to do. Is there another way to do this or a database command I could use to do this?
  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can add new question and this part is for posting answers only. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If this data is important for you get a backup of this table.

I've experienced this problem several times and solved with this way;
Try to truncate catalogsearch_query table.

TRUNCATE TABLE catalogsearch_query;

Answer (score -5):

I assume you followed all comments above apart from that please follow the following too:

1. First Make sure you have max execution time either write in index.php
      `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800)` or set it in php.ini `max_execution_time= 1600`
2. Increase memory limit
       `ini_set('memory_limit','512M')` or set it in php.ini `memory_limit=16M`

Comment: how would 16M refer to an increase ... Magento is 256/512M  ... spammy response?

Comment: sorry edited it.