# Magento 1.9.3.2 search returns empty result

Tags: magento-1.9, search, indexing

After upgrading the magento search is not working.

I tried this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/67952

> SELECT `e`.*, `search_result`.`relevance`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>    INNER JOIN `catalogsearch_result` AS `search_result` ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='43'
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
>    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'

**Result:**

```
Array (
    [class] => Mage_CatalogSearch_Model
    [resourceModel] => catalogsearch_resource
    [rewrite] => Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
        (
            [layer_filter_attribute] => WeltPixel_LayeredNavigation_Model_CatalogSearch_Layer_Filter_Attribute
        ) 
)
```

When I checked the tables, I can find that **`catalogsearch_result`** table seems always empty. But **catalogsearch_query** and **`catalogsearch_fulltext`** tables have content.

Why this table shows empty? 
How can I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1.9.3.x, `catalogsearch_result` table is NO longer used I think.

There are minor differences/changes in `CatalogSearch` module in 1.9.3.x and 1.9.0.x versions.

You can check `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Fulltext.php`, here NEW property `_foundData` is added which holds FullText search results instead saving in `catalogsearch_result` table.

Check `prepareResult` method of both versions,

In 1.9.3.x versions,

```
$this->_foundData = $adapter->fetchPairs($select, $bind);
```

In 1.9.0.x versions,

```
$sql = $adapter->insertFromSelect($select,
    $this->getTable('catalogsearch/result'),
    array(),
    Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE);
$adapter->query($sql, $bind);
```

**What should be done now (for 1.9.3.x versions) ?**

You can use `getFoundData` method of this class to get results :

```
$searchText = STRING_TO_SEARCH;
$query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->loadByQueryText($searchText);
if($query->getId()){
    $fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
        Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'), 
        $query->getQueryText(), 
        $query
    );
    $prod_ids = $fulltextResource->getFoundData();
    //print_r($prod_ids);
}
```

Here `$prod_ids` is an Array variable which contains Product Id and No. of count as Key=>Value pair.

Comment: hi @anilsuthar , can you please in which file we should place the code , that you mentioned for magento 1.9.3 , i am facing the same proble  so it might help

Comment: @Kumar You should override the class and implement the code shown above. May be this class : app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Fulltext.php

Answer (score 1):

Try run re-index
Go to the system menu and index management.