# Magento 1.9.3.10 - Search doesn't work, advanced does!

Tags: search, catalogsearch, advanced-search, magento-1.9.3.10

Hi guys got a weird one the normal magento search returns 0 results, but the advanced search works?

Tried:

- Reindexing
- Clearing Cache
- Re updating attributes of products to link
  to website
- Checked for theme files overriding (have I missed any?)

I edited "Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer"

And added:

```
Mage::log($collection->getSelectSQL(1), false, 'search.log', true);
Mage::log((array)Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->catalogsearch, false, 'search.log', true)
```

Which gave me the SQL query, ran it in MySQL and returned a load of products as it should!

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: did you go through [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67512/search-does-not-return-results) check [this](https://mirasvit.com/knowledge-base/magento-search-no-results.html) also

Comment: @Hit's yes I have been through both of those